Baseuri structure
I'm testing on Sepolia a basic NFT contract where images and json is hosted on a centralized server.
The fact is that I still don't see my NFT images in Metamask. Is this because a testnet doesn't display them?
Also:

Is it ok to point the baseuri to the server root (ip-address) if the
json files are in the server root?
Should the baseuri be https://xx.xx.xx.xx/json if the json files are in the json folder?

My folder structure is:
/htdocs/
├── 1.json
├── 2.json
├── ...

        └── images/
          ├── 1.png
          ├── 2.png
          ├── ...

Before that my json files were in a separate json folder but while testing I moved them afterwards.
A json file looks like this:
"name": "Test Collection",
    "description": "The Test Collection",
    "image": "https://xx.xx.xx.xx/images/4.png" ,
    "attributes": [
      {
          "trait_type": "color",
          "value": "red"
      },
...

In the contract, baseuri is: string public baseURI = "https://xx.xx.xx.xx/";
This is the token contract: 0xF2eAB12E5220cA3042CFcf037CdD8B9fFa0B0824
Hope I'm not too confusing here :)
Thank you;

Are you able to see your NFT on Opensea Testnet?

Nope, images aren't viewable.
